# exe with pytz-2018.3.dist not working. raises UnknownTimeZoneError

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, pytz

I'm having a problem when building an `exe` from my scripts that use the pytz lib. I'm constantly getting the error:

```
File "pytz\__init__.pyc", line 180, in timezone UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Europe\Ljubljana'
```

No matter how I build the `exe` I get this error. Running the script works. I tried all suggestions that were posted here and on other sites.

My setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import os.path
try:
    import py2exe
    has_py2exe = True
except ImportError, e:
    has_py2exe = False

myScript=__import__("myScript")

options = {'py2exe': {'packages': ['pytz']}}

options['py2exe'] = {'dist_dir': 'dist'}
setup(
    name="myScript",
    version=myScript.CONST_VERSION,
    console=[{
        'script': 'myScript.py',
        'copyright': 'None',
        'company_name': 'None'
    }],
    options=options,
)

if has_py2exe:
    import zipfile
    zipfile_path = os.path.join(options['py2exe']['dist_dir'], 'library.zip')
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_path, 'a')

    import pytz
    assert (pytz.__file__.endswith('__init__.pyc') or pytz.__file__.endswith('__init__.py')), pytz.__file__
    zoneinfo_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pytz.__file__), 'zoneinfo')
    disk_basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(pytz.__file__))
    for absdir, directories, filenames in os.walk(zoneinfo_dir):
        assert absdir.startswith(disk_basedir), (absdir, disk_basedir)
        zip_dir = absdir[len(disk_basedir):]
        for f in filenames:
            z.write(os.path.join(absdir, f), os.path.join(zip_dir, f))
    z.close()
```

This builds the exe and includes the zoneinfo dir and all timezone files to library.zip.

I only use the pytz in one function where I convert the CEST timestamp to UTC timestamp to store on the server.

The function:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def date_time_utc(date_str):
    date_tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Ljubljana")

    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    date_str_dt_object = datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt)

    date_str_dt_object = date_tz.localize(date_str_dt_object)
    date_utc = date_str_dt_object.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))

    return date_utc.strftime(fmt)
```

The setup script for the pytz is from [here](https://github.com/google/transitfeed/blob/master/setup.py). All other things like [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158846/unknowntimezoneerror-exception-raised-with-python-application-compiled-with-py2e) and any other suggested fixes raised the exactly same error.
Has any one figured out how to get this working?

Comment: I worked around this problem by formatting the date with query because MSSQL has this option "SELECT *, DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), myDate) AS utc_myDate". But I would really like to know how to build a exe with working pytz lib